# Running celeryd_multi with supervisor

Tags: celery, django-celery, supervisord, background-foreground

I'm working with djcelery and supervisor.
I was running a celery with supervisor and everything worked fine, once I realized that I needed to change it to celery multi everything broke up.
If I run celeryd_multi in a terminal it works but always run in background, like supervisor need that the command run in foreground there where the problem is.

This is my `celery.ini`:

```
[program:celery_{{ division }}]
command = {{ virtualenv_bin_dir }}/python manage.py celeryd_multi start default mailchimp -c:mailchimp 3 -c:default 5 --loglevel=info --logfile={{ log_dir }}/celery/%n.log --pidfile={{ run_dir }}/celery/%n.pid --schedule=/home/celery/celerybeat-schedule --settings={{ django_settings_python_path }}
autorestart = false
autostart = false
directory = {{ repo_dir }}/{{ division }}
user=celery
numprocs = 1
redirect_stderr = True
stopwaitsecs = 10
startsecs = 10
priority = 997
startretries = 3
```

Here is the command I put in the terminal that works fine

`python manage.py celeryd_multi start default mailchimp -c:mailchimp 3 -c:default 5 --loglevel=info --logfile=/var/log/celery/%n.log --pidfile=/var/log/celery/%n.pid --schedule=/home/celery/celerybeat-schedule --settings=lively.settings_gunicorn`

Answer (score 7):

[Reply from the main developer of celery](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/celery-users/oQh7mJOV-G8) (23 Mar 2012):

> I'm not aware of any simple solution to start multiple celeryd instances
>   using supervisor, but you can always use one config for each. Maybe someone
>   else has a solution for it though.
>
> The generic-init.d/celeryd script uses celeryd-multi to start multiple servers,
>   and you can use the CELERYD_NODES /etc/init.d/celeryd variable to set a number, or
>   a list of worker names.
>   I'm not sure how supervisord could be made to work with celeryd-multi, as it would
>   probably need to know which of the resulting PIDs should be monitored or not (maybe a supervisord
>   plugin could be written?)
>
> -- Ask Solem

Answer (score 0):

Daemontools has a utility called fghack designed to make a background process "stay" in the foreground.

pidsig supposedly is similar, but proxies signals:

```
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.supervision.general/2010

https://github.com/chexum/pidsig/blob/master/pidsig.c
```

I believe both are basically wrappers that wait on the backgrounded children.