# Celeryd multi with supervisord

Tags: python, celery, supervisord, celeryd

Trying to run supervisord (3.2.2) with celery multi.

Seems to be that supervisord can't handle it. Single celery worker works fine.

This is my supervisord configuration

```
celery multi v3.1.20 (Cipater)
> Starting nodes...
    > celery1@parzee-dev-app-sfo1: OK
Stale pidfile exists. Removing it.
    > celery2@parzee-dev-app-sfo1: OK
Stale pidfile exists. Removing it.
```

celeryd.conf

```
; ==================================
;  celery worker supervisor example
; ==================================

[program:celery]
; Set full path to celery program if using virtualenv
command=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/supervisorctl/celeryd/celeryd.sh
process_name = %(program_name)s%(process_num)d@%(host_node_name)s
directory=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/conf/
numprocs=2
stderr_logfile=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.err
logfile=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.log
stdout_logfile_backups = 10
stderr_logfile_backups = 10
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
autostart=true
autorestart=false
startsecs=10
```

Im using the following supervisord variables to emulate the way I start celery:

- %(program_name)s
- %(process_num)d
- @
- %(host_node_name)s

Supervisorctl

```
supervisorctl 
celery:celery1@parzee-dev-app-sfo1   FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
celery:celery2@parzee-dev-app-sfo1   FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
```

I tried changing this value in /`usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py from 0 to 1:`

```
numprocs_start = integer(get(section, 'numprocs_start', 1))
```

I still get:

```
celery:celery1@parzee-dev-app-sfo1   FATAL     Exited too quickly (process log may have details)
celery:celery2@parzee-dev-app-sfo1   EXITED    May 14 12:47 AM
```

Celery is starting but supervisord is not keeping track of it.

root@parzee-dev-app-sfo1:/etc/supervisor#

```
ps -ef | grep celery
root      2728     1  1 00:46 ?        00:00:02 [celeryd: celery1@parzee-dev-app-sfo1:MainProcess] -active- (worker -c 16 -n celery1@parzee-dev-app-sfo1 --loglevel=DEBUG -P processes --logfile=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.log --pidfile=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/1.pid)
root      2973     1  1 00:46 ?        00:00:02 [celeryd: celery2@parzee-dev-app-sfo1:MainProcess] -active- (worker -c 16 -n celery2@parzee-dev-app-sfo1 --loglevel=DEBUG -P processes --logfile=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.log --pidfile=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/2.pid)
```

celery.sh

```
source ~/.profile
CELERY_LOGFILE=/usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/log/celeryd.log
CELERYD_OPTS=" --loglevel=DEBUG"
CELERY_WORKERS=2
CELERY_PROCESSES=16
cd /usr/local/src/imbue/application/imbue/conf
exec celery multi start $CELERY_WORKERS -P processes -c $CELERY_PROCESSES -n celeryd@{HOSTNAME} -f $CELERY_LOGFILE $CELERYD_OPTS
```

Similar:
[Running celeryd_multi with supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558875/running-celeryd-multi-with-supervisor)
[How to use Supervisor + Django + Celery with multiple Queues and Workers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001788/how-to-use-supervisor-django-celery-with-multiple-queues-and-workers)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since supervisor monitors(start/stop/restart) process, the process should be run in foreground(**should not be daemonized**).

Celery multi daemonizes itself, so it can't be run with supervisor.

You can create separate process for each worker and group them into one.

```
[program:worker1]
command=celery worker -l info -n worker1

[program:worker2]
command=celery worker -l info -n worker2

[group:workers]
programs=worker1,worker2
```

You can also write a shell script which [makes daemon process run in foreground](https://serverfault.com/questions/608069/managing-daemons-with-supervisor-no-foreground-mode-available/608073#608073) like this.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

pidfile="/var/run/your-daemon.pid"
command=/usr/sbin/your-daemon

# Proxy signals
function kill_app(){
    kill $(cat $pidfile)
    exit 0 # exit okay
}
trap "kill_app" SIGINT SIGTERM

# Launch daemon
$ celery multi start 2 -l INFO

sleep 2

# Loop while the pidfile and the process exist
while [ -f $pidfile ] && kill -0 $(cat $pidfile) ; do
    sleep 0.5
done
exit 1000 # exit unexpected
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up splitting my multi configurarion into single workers